# Loop through the records and find the nearest match and write the result to a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql

All data is initially contained in one table `#T1_rate_trans`
At the moment I am starting my loop by creating two separate temp tables `#trn_CR1` and `#trn_DR1` where there are still CR records to be matched

```
DECLARE @count int
SET @count = 0
WHILE (select count(*) from #T1_rate_trans where tran_type = 'CR' and balance <>0)>0
BEGIN
    /****  drop temp table ****/
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#trn_CR1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #trn_CR1;
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#trn_DR1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #trn_DR1;
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#trn_matched1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #trn_matched1;
    /**** 4. CR trans ****/
SELECT  * 
into #trn_CR1
FROM #T1_rate_trans 
WHERE balance <> 0  and tran_type = 'CR' 
ORDER BY record_id,ass_num,rte_cde,rte_dif,trn_dte
    /**** 5. DR trans ****/
CREATE TABLE #trn_DR1
(
Record_ID_DR int NOT NULL,
ass_num_DR int NOT NULL,
trn_dte_DR datetime NOT NULL,
trn_num_DR int NOT NULL,
trn_lin_DR int NULL,
trn_cde_DR smallint NOT NULL,
rte_cde_DR smallint NOT NULL,
rte_dif_DR smallint NOT NULL,
bal_cde_DR smallint NOT NULL,
trn_ref_DR varchar(40) NULL,
amount_exc_DR money NOT NULL,
tax_DR money NOT NULL,
amount_inc_DR money NOT NULL,
cre_dte_tme_DR datetime NOT NULL,
rte_yer_DR smallint NOT NULL,
tran_type_DR varchar(2) NOT NULL,
ABS_amount_inc_DR money NOT NULL,
applied_amt_DR money NULL,
balance_DR money NULL,
record_applied_to_DR int NULL
) 
;
-- Insert DR transactions FROM T1_Rate_trans
INSERT INTO #trn_DR1
(Record_ID_DR
,ass_num_DR
,trn_dte_DR
,trn_num_DR
,trn_lin_DR
,trn_cde_DR
,rte_cde_DR
,rte_dif_DR
,bal_cde_DR
,trn_ref_DR
,amount_exc_DR
,tax_DR
,amount_inc_DR
,cre_dte_tme_DR
,rte_yer_DR
,tran_type_DR
,ABS_amount_inc_DR
,applied_amt_DR
,balance_DR
,record_applied_to_DR
)
SELECT * FROM #T1_Rate_Trans 
WHERE balance <> 0  and tran_type = 'DR'
ORDER BY ass_num,rte_cde,rte_dif,trn_dte
;
```

My first table contains CR records and looks like this

| Record_ID | ass_num | rte_cde | rte_dif | bal_cde | amount_exc | tax | amount_inc | cre_dte_tme | rte_yer | ABS_amount_inc | applied_amt | balance | record_applied_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 100014 | 1 | 5 | 21 | -944.6 | 0 | -944.6 | 21/10/2003 | 2004 | 944.6 | 0 | -944.6 |  |
| 12 | 100014 | 1 | 5 | 21 | -1290.58 | 0 | -1290.58 | 9/01/2004 | 2004 | 1290.58 | 0 | -1290.58 |  |
| 174 | 101335 | 1 | 5 | 21 | -899.39 | 0 | -899.39 | 10/11/2003 | 2004 | 899.39 | 0 | -899.39 |  |
| 175 | 101335 | 1 | 5 | 23 | -9.75 | 0 | -9.75 | 10/11/2003 | 2004 | 9.75 | 0 | -9.75 |  |
| 187 | 101335 | 1 | 5 | 21 | -1457.85 | 0 | -1457.85 | 30/12/2003 | 2004 | 1457.85 | 0 | -1457.85 |  |
| 191 | 101335 | 1 | 5 | 21 | -1528.85 | 0 | -1528.85 | 25/02/2004 | 2004 | 1528.85 | 0 | -1528.85 |  |
| 193 | 101335 | 1 | 5 | 21 | -1518.97 | 0 | -1518.97 | 15/04/2004 | 2004 | 1518.97 | 0 | -1518.97 |  |
| 194 | 101335 | 1 | 5 | 23 | -10.4 | 0 | -10.4 | 15/04/2004 | 2004 | 10.4 | 0 | -10.4 |  |
| 621 | 101335 | 90 | 1 | 21 | -9 | 0 | -9 | 1/07/2003 | 2004 | 9 | 0 | -9 |  |
| 622 | 101335 | 91 | 1 | 21 | -70.00 | 0 | -70.00 | 1/07/2003 | 2004 | 70.00 | 0 | -70.00 |  |

My second table contains the DR records and looks like this

| Record_ID_DR | ass_num_DR | rte_cde_DR | rte_dif_DR | bal_cde_DR | amount_exc_DR | tax_DR | amount_inc_DR | cre_dte_tme_DR | rte_yer_DR | ABS_amount_inc_DR | applied_amt_DR | balance_DR | record_applied_to_DR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100014 | 1 | 5 | 21 | 2235.18 | 0 | 2235.18 | 12/09/2003 | 2004 | 2235.18 | 0 | 2235.18 |  |
| 168 | 101335 | 1 | 5 | 21 | 5405.06 | 0 | 5405.06 | 12/09/2003 | 2004 | 5405.06 | 0 | 5405.06 |  |
| 185 | 101335 | 90 | 1 | 21 | 9 | 0 | 9 | 1/07/2003 | 2004 | 9 | 0 | 9 |  |
| 186 | 101335 | 91 | 1 | 21 | 65.62 | 0 | 65.62 | 1/07/2003 | 2004 | 65.62 | 0 | 65.62 |  |

I then need to match the records from the two tables based on a number of fields which I do via the following. They can only be included in the match if the balance or balance_DR value <> 0 AND the CR amount is <= the DR amount AND I only want to write the first first match which is why I am using the rn = 1 criteria below.

```
/**** 6. create temp table for matched transaction ids ****/
     CREATE TABLE #trn_matched1
    (Credit_Record_ID int
    ,Debit_Record_ID int)

    /**** 7. insert matched transactions into temp table ****/
INSERT INTO #trn_matched1
SELECT t.Record_ID,t.Record_ID_DR
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CR.Record_ID,CR.ass_num,cr.amount_inc, DR.Record_ID_DR,DR.ass_num_DR,DR.amount_inc_DR
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CR.ass_num,rte_cde,rte_dif ORDER BY CR.ass_num,rte_cde,rte_dif ) rn
FROM 
    #trn_CR1 CR, #trn_DR1 DR
WHERE 
    CR.ass_num = DR.ass_num_DR
    and
    CR.rte_cde = DR.rte_cde_DR
    and
    CR.rte_dif = DR.rte_dif_DR
    and
    CR.rte_yer <= DR.rte_yer_DR
    and 
    CR.ABS_amount_inc <= DR.ABS_amount_inc_DR
    and 
    DR.cre_dte_tme_DR <= CR.cre_dte_tme
    AND (CR.balance <> 0 or DR.balance_DR <> 0)) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The results from the inner SQL above, without the t.rn=1 criteria,  looks like this

| Record_ID | ass_num | amount_inc | Record_ID_DR | ass_num_DR | amount_inc_DR | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 100014 | -944.6 | 2 | 100014 | 2235.18 | 1 |
| 12 | 100014 | -1290.6 | 2 | 100014 | 2235.18 | 2 |
| 174 | 101335 | -899.39 | 168 | 101335 | 5405.06 | 1 |
| 175 | 101335 | -9.75 | 168 | 101335 | 5405.06 | 2 |
| 187 | 101335 | -1457.9 | 168 | 101335 | 5405.06 | 3 |
| 191 | 101335 | -1528.9 | 168 | 101335 | 5405.06 | 4 |
| 193 | 101335 | -1519 | 168 | 101335 | 5405.06 | 5 |
| 194 | 101335 | -10.4 | 168 | 101335 | 5405.06 | 6 |
| 621 | 101335 | -9 | 185 | 101335 | 9 | 1 |

I only want the first match i.e.
Record_ID 5 to Record_ID_DR 2
Record_ID 174 to Record_ID_DR 168
Record_ID 621 to Record_ID_DR 185

After the match above I have a number of steps that update the balance and applied amounts in the `#T1_rate_trans` table and writes some data to another table. I then start the loop again. i.e. remove the `#trn_CR1` and `#trn_DR1` tables and recreate them as the records that match the criteria have now changed i.e. balance/balance_DR <> 0

The problem I am encountering is that the loop becomes a continuous loop as there are instances where I have records in `#trn_CR1` that have a balance and rn =1 but there are no records in the `#trn_DR1` table that they can be matched to because the exact match criteria cannot be met - this is usually because the `#trn_CR1.ABS_amount_inc` is greater that the `#trn_DR1.ABS_amount_inc_DR` eg Record 622 from the `#trn_CR1` table and Record 186 from `#trn_DR1`

I know I need to put a BREAK in somewhere but for the life of me I can't work out where or how.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Hmm, not really clear to me. I guess you should create a minimized presentation of the problem to be discussed here. See [example]. But a general hint: If find yourself using loops in SQL, you're very likely to be on the wrong path. DBMS excel at set based operations, when it comes to loop through records, they suck.

Comment: Agree with @stickybit. I have made a *partial* solution of your problem on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d750/5) feel free to check and update your question with more details. BTW  _I only want the first match_ is aleatory for me the first match is the `MIN` value.

Comment: Apologies, I thought i had provided enough info. However, thanks to @Max I have now managed to come up with a solution